# Insert a script tag into Delve / customization possibilities of Delve?

Tags: office-365

I would like to insert a small bit of script inside Delve app from Office 365. Is there a way to insert a script into it? (like it is in SharePoint a Script Link custom action) Or is there a way to customize anything from the Delve experience?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delve does not support any customizations at the moment. You can only change the Delve theme, which is user specific setting or customize suite navigation with Office 365 themes.

This basically means that you cannot use a custom master page or add any custom scripts on the page. These options are not available.

If there's any specific suggestions which you'd like to see in Delve, would suggest to use UserVoice for those submissions.